# overflow hidden doesnt seem to work in firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm having a small problem with my project, I have made a sliding wall with css, it looks ok in chrome but I have no idea why it doesnt work with firefox as it gives me a large overflow to the side.

It looks like its something to do with `<div class=info>`
but it something else might be causing it.

This code is from a tutorial which should work as I have not changed much, I thought that `<div id=overflow>` which just has this as css

> #overflow {
>   width: 100%;
>   overflow: hidden;
>   min-height: 600px;
>   }

would do the job but not in my case.

Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/NuBys/) to the jsFiddle to show the problem

Right now I have no idea what is causing the problem, notice the scroll bar at the bottom of the site when using firefox.

How can this problem be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/NuBys/3/)
All you have to do is to add `position:relative;` into your `#overflow`. This is working in my firefox 20.0.1

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in firefox:

```
#overflow {
width: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden !important;
position:relative !important;
min-height: 600px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

It seems to correct the issue in Firefox. It does mean that if the browser window is narrower than the content, the user won't be able to scroll to see the hidden content.

Comment: Does this mean Firefox is the new IE? Forcing people to add more code just to make it work? :p

Comment: I don't think so -- `overflow: hidden;` works correctly for me in other instances in Firefox. I'd have to dig around in the code a bit deeper to find out why it's not working in this case.